# Excel VBA Macro - Set Row Variables On Separate Sheets Equal to Each Other

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I've found questions and answers very similar to my question, but nothing that addresses the specific question I have.  With my macro I want to say:

If Column "M", Row 6 on the Analysis Worksheet is not empty AND Column "B" Row 6 AND Column "C" Row 6 AND Column "D" Row 6 (all on Analysis Worksheet) are empty AND Column "C" Row 6 on Fixed Cost Test Data Worksheet is not empty AND the value of Column "C" Row 6 on Fixed Cost Test Data is >= Today's Date, THEN I want the value of Column "M", Row 6 on the Analysis Worksheet to be calculated as:

`Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Range("M" & i).Value = (Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Range("M" & i).Value - Sheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & j).Value) - ((Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Range("M" & i).Value - Sheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & j).Value) * (Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Range("E" & i).Value * 0.01))`

I want i = j.  i and j are the same number/same row.

What do I need to change in my code so when it performs calculations for a row on Analysis Worksheet, it is using the same row's values on Fixed Cost Test Data Worksheet and the rows stay 'in sync' as they move down the worksheet together?

This is the code I have for the macro:

```
Sub ReduceCost_Percentage()

    With Worksheets("Analysis Worksheet")

        Dim i As Long
        Dim LastRow As Long
        LastRow = Range("X" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        Dim j As Long
        j = i
        Dim LRow As Long
        LRow = Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 5 To LastRow
            For j = i To i

                If Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Range("E" & i).Value > 0 And IsEmpty(Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Range("B" & i).Value) _
                   And IsEmpty(Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Range("C" & i).Value) And IsEmpty(Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Range("D" & i).Value) _
                   And Not IsEmpty(Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Range("M" & i).Value) And Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & j).Value) And (Date >= Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & j).Value) Then

                    Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Range("M" & i).Value = (Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Range("M" & i).Value - Sheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & j).Value) - ((Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Range("M" & i).Value - Sheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & j).Value) * (Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Range("E" & i).Value * 0.01))

                ElseIf Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Range("E" & i).Value > 0 And IsEmpty(Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Range("B" & i).Value) _
                       And IsEmpty(Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Range("C" & i).Value) And IsEmpty(Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Range("D" & i).Value) _
                       And Not IsEmpty(Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Range("M" & i).Value) And (IsEmpty(Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & j).Value) Or Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & j).Value > Date) Then

                    Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Range("M" & i).Value = Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Range("M" & i).Value - (Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Range("M" & i).Value * (Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Range("E" & i).Value * 0.01))

                End If

            Next j
        Next i

        For i = 5 To LastRow
            For j = i To i

                If Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Range("E" & i).Value > 0 And IsEmpty(Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Range("B" & i).Value) _
                   And IsEmpty(Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Range("C" & i).Value) And IsEmpty(Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Range("D" & i).Value) _
                   And Not IsEmpty(Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Range("N" & i).Value) And Not IsEmpty(Sheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & j).Value) And (Date >= Sheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & j).Value) Then

                    Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Range("N" & i).Value = (Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Range("N" & i).Value - Sheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & j).Value) - ((Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Range("N" & i).Value - Sheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & j).Value) * (Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Range("E" & i).Value * 0.01))

                ElseIf Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Range("E" & i).Value > 0 And IsEmpty(Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Range("B" & i).Value) _
                       And IsEmpty(Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Range("C" & i).Value) And IsEmpty(Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Range("D" & i).Value) _
                       And Not IsEmpty(Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Range("N" & i).Value) And (IsEmpty(Sheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & j).Value) Or Sheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & j).Value > Date) Then

                    Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Range("N" & i).Value = Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Range("N" & i).Value - (Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Range("N" & i).Value * (Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Range("E" & i).Value * 0.01))

                End If

            Next j
        Next i

        '....Continues until Cell "X"

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: tl;dr but if you want same row, start on same row and increment equally?

Comment: @findwindow, could you please elaborate on your answer?  What do you mean by 'increment equally'?

Comment: It looks like you already are. `For j = i To i` if `i=5`, then you're doing `j=5 to 5` no? Edit: I think you just need a third increment variable.

Comment: You aren't instantiating your variables.  When you first assign `j = i`, `i` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things: when you are using a "with" block (such as `With Worksheets("Analysis Worksheet")`) you can omit that from pretty much all the code within that block.  Also, `For j = i To i` will do nothing, it's done when it starts.  You probably wanted to use Lrow.

Maybe this will work better:

```
Sub ReduceCost_Percentage()

    With Worksheets("Analysis Worksheet")

        Dim i As Long
        Dim LastRow As Long
        LastRow = Range("X" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        Dim j As Long
        Dim LRow As Long
        LRow = Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 5 To LastRow
            For j = i To LRow

                If .Range("E" & i).Value > 0 And IsEmpty(.Range("B" & i).Value) _
                   And IsEmpty(.Range("C" & i).Value) And IsEmpty(.Range("D" & i).Value) _
                   And Not IsEmpty(.Range("M" & i).Value) And Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & j).Value) And (Date >= Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & j).Value) Then

                    .Range("M" & i).Value = (.Range("M" & i).Value - Sheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & j).Value) - ((.Range("M" & i).Value - Sheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & j).Value) * (.Range("E" & i).Value * 0.01))

                ElseIf .Range("E" & i).Value > 0 And IsEmpty(.Range("B" & i).Value) _
                       And IsEmpty(.Range("C" & i).Value) And IsEmpty(.Range("D" & i).Value) _
                       And Not IsEmpty(.Range("M" & i).Value) And (IsEmpty(Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & j).Value) Or Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & j).Value > Date) Then

                    .Range("M" & i).Value = .Range("M" & i).Value - (.Range("M" & i).Value * (.Range("E" & i).Value * 0.01))

                End If

            Next j
        Next i

        For i = 5 To LastRow
            For j = i To LRow

                If .Range("E" & i).Value > 0 And IsEmpty(.Range("B" & i).Value) _
                   And IsEmpty(.Range("C" & i).Value) And IsEmpty(.Range("D" & i).Value) _
                   And Not IsEmpty(.Range("N" & i).Value) And Not IsEmpty(Sheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & j).Value) And (Date >= Sheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & j).Value) Then

                    .Range("N" & i).Value = (.Range("N" & i).Value - Sheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & j).Value) - ((.Range("N" & i).Value - Sheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & j).Value) * (.Range("E" & i).Value * 0.01))

                ElseIf .Range("E" & i).Value > 0 And IsEmpty(.Range("B" & i).Value) _
                       And IsEmpty(.Range("C" & i).Value) And IsEmpty(.Range("D" & i).Value) _
                       And Not IsEmpty(.Range("N" & i).Value) And (IsEmpty(Sheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & j).Value) Or Sheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & j).Value > Date) Then

                    .Range("N" & i).Value = .Range("N" & i).Value - (.Range("N" & i).Value * (.Range("E" & i).Value * 0.01))

                End If

            Next j
        Next i

        '....Continues until Cell "X"

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks n8!  I figured out the problem with my code was the Date function.  Where I had `Date >= Sheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & j).Value Then` I should have had `TodayDate >= Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & i).Value Then'.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I'm posting this as an answer because it was too long to put in the comment box.

Thanks n8!  I figured out the problem with my code was the Date function, and I didn't need a separate variable (j) for the row number on my 2nd worksheet.  Where I had `Date >= Sheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & j).Value Then`, I should have had `TodayDate >= Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & i).Value Then`.  My new working code is:

```
Sub ReduceCost_Percentage()

With Worksheets("Analysis Worksheet")

Dim i As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Range("X" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim TodayDate As Date
TodayDate = Format(Date, "DD/MM/YYYY")

For i = 5 To LastRow
 If .Range("E" & i).Value > 0 And IsEmpty(.Range("B" & i).Value) _
 And IsEmpty(.Range("C" & i).Value) And IsEmpty(.Range("D" & i).Value) _
 And Not IsEmpty(.Range("M" & i).Value) And Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & i).Value) _
 And TodayDate >= Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & i).Value Then
  .Range("M" & i).Value = (.Range("M" & i).Value - Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & i).Value) - ((.Range("M" & i).Value - Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & i).Value) * (.Range("E" & i).Value * 0.01))
 ElseIf .Range("E" & i).Value > 0 And IsEmpty(.Range("B" & i).Value) _
 And IsEmpty(.Range("C" & i).Value) And IsEmpty(.Range("D" & i).Value) _
 And Not IsEmpty(.Range("M" & i).Value) And (IsEmpty(Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & i).Value) Or Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & i).Value > Date) Then
  .Range("M" & i).Value = .Range("M" & i).Value - (.Range("M" & i).Value * (.Range("E" & i).Value * 0.01))
 End If
Next I
```

Thanks!!